# Problem running an encrypted singularity container

Tags: singularity-container

I've created an encrypted singularity container using the PEM file encryption method (paragraph 3.3 of the documentation). But when I try to run it I get an error message :

FATAL:   Invalid encryption private key: asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:1 tag:15 length:112 isCompound:true}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false private:false defaultValue: tag: stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} pkcs1PrivateKey @2

Any hint on what goes wrong ?
Thank you,
Michal

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in an OpenSSH update (version 7.8). Thats why some people have this problem and some don't.

To cite the release notes: `write OpenSSH format private keys by default instead of using OpenSSL's PEM format`

So the correct command to generate the keys should be `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m pem -N "" -f ./rsa`
By adding the `-m pem` you get the key in the correct format.

More here: https://github.com/hpcng/singularity/issues/6007

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two issues that could cause the error message: (1) the keypair should be generated with -m pem option to have the pem format and (2) the keypair should not have password protection I dont think it is supported by singularity at this  point in time.